# How to fix, showing logo in home page in mobile version?

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with the logo in a site on wordpress. The problem is, that the logo appear in every page in desktop, in every page in mobile, but the only page that doesn't appear the logo, is the home page of mobile.
Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can u send a link to the website? It's impossible to figure out what is going on without that.

Comment: By this time, i'm working on this site on a localhost, so i don't have a link for now

Comment: Can u take video? gif? I would like to see desktop and mobile version when its working, and when its not.